# Xamarin: publish iOS to App Store from Visual Studio no working

Tags: xamarin, ipa, distribute

I'm actively using Visual Studio 16.6 windows / 8.6.1 macOS to build and test iOS / Android application, in Xamarin Forms. macOS is running Xcode 11.

I can't push to AppStoreConnect from "Sign and Distribute" directly.

Everything is working fine step by step: build in release for iDevice, signing and distribution profile accepted, export to IPA file, and uploading via Xcode->Organizer. But i'd like to do this simply from Visual Studio; either on my PC or mac.

I have the following errors on Visual Studio / windows when uploading to AppStoreConnect:

```
Error: unable to create IPA file for distribution of archive myApp
MessagingRemoteException: error happened on client Build160001055 during execution of an answer for category xvs/Build/16.6.0.1055/execute-task/myApp.iOS/c1cf1c8002fCopy
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy' threw an exception.
PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
```

I have the following error on Visual Studio / macOS when uploading to AppStoreConnect:

```
Publication failure: we are unable to create an authentification session.
```

Notice Visual Studio / macOS is asking creds (i'm using developper account) while Visual Studio / windows is not (i surely have it registered before, but i don't remember).

Comment: please do not post errors as images

Comment: Make sure that the version of VS and Xcode are up to date  . In addition, check if you had logined the Apple Developer account  currently .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thx, they are up to date. The windows error is strange, while the macOS one seems related to credentials - but the window displaying info is too small, i can't read and perhaps i miss the point. will try to see in documentation if i can find more details on this window, perhaps i could at least have this feature working in macOS.

Comment: I am having this same issue when attempting to build the .ipa for the first time on a new project.  This must be a new issue, as I am unable to find any other posts referencing this exact messaging.

Comment: Related to the second message in Visual Studio / mac, this is because, for VS mac (and not for Xcode !) i need an "application password" that is linked to this application and that you could generate in https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage / Security / application password. Not linked to initial trouble. After the fix, Visual Studio PC need it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears to have been resolved in a hotfix (16.6.1) released today, as per this bug report:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/961282/xamarinios-fails-to-build-with-messagingremoteexce.html